# Вывод списка ArrayList<String> переданный через интент в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Всем привет. Возник такой вопрос:
Имеется фрагмент который передаёт `String [] title = {"00.Глава1","01.Глава2",}`в активность.

**Передаю из Fragment:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(Arrays.toString(title));
        intent.putExtra("title", array);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
        startActivity(intent);
```

**Получаю в активности Activity1:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> title_array= (ArrayList<String>) 
    getIntent().getSerializableExtra("title");
```

*Устанавливаю массив в ListView:*

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, title_array.toArray(new String[0]));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Данные я получаю , и массив строк отображается , но не в виде списка listView.
В чём я ошибаюсь, почему **Activity1** не выводит массив в виде списка ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я допускаю что вы не совсем правильно устанавливаете массив в виджет. Вот эта строка:

```
title_array.toArray(new String[0])
```

для меня лично выглядит как сеттинг в виджет списка с размером 0. Я могу конечно ошибаться, но вы можете проверить массив который приходит в активность и что получается после того как вы его конвертируете в такой массив, например выведите его в логи. Вот есть пример как использовать list и arraylist в нужном вам виджете:

```
List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
your_array_list.add("foo");
your_array_list.add("bar");

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
your_array_list );

lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за подсказку , я понял свою ошибку . Где хотел передать  `array.add(Arrays.toString(title));` и получал весь список без индекса , я переписал на `array.add("Глава1"); array.add("Глава1");` и всё заработало.